# How can I write php tests for third party oauth authentication?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing

I am writing an application which requires authentication from Github API v3. One of my main goals for this application is to have full test coverage.

The application is written with `Silex` with controllers defined in different files.

How would I test third party authentication with `PHPUnit`? Or do I need something like `Behat`?

Comment: This is the kind of issue I face everyday implementing Facebook/Google/Twitter/GitHub ...  OAuth.

I can say that [Facebook provide test apps and users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users) for this specific purpose. I cannot find similar feature on other platforms.

I would recommand to use a functional test framework like Behat to test it.

Comment: Look ate [Testing a Basic Auth symfony API with behat3](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/l41o/testing-a-basic-auth-symfony-api-with-behat3) and [Mocking internal or external service or api calls with behat](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/2y8u/mocking-internal-or-external-service-or-api-calls-with-behat). You can use either one but I suggest mocking.